# collection.Aggregate not working on array of objects which has another array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have been trying to make a get request in Node.js using mongoose and mongodb.

My user has a list of farms array objects  which have devices array objects. I am querying and trying to get a specific device's field.

Here I tried to use aggregate function but it's returning empty array.

**Back-end Code**

```
router.get("/getParameter/:farmID/:deviceID",async(req,res)=>{
  User.aggregate([
    {$match:{"farm._id":req.params.farmID}},
    {$unwind:'$farm'},
    {$match:{"device._id":req.params.deviceID}},
    {$unwind:'$device'},
    {$match:{"device.Parameter":{$exists:true}}},
    {$project:{"Parameter":1}}
  ]).exec((err,result)=>{
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(result)
    res.send(result)
  });
})
```

**User Schema**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

//Device Schema
const Device = new Schema({
  deviceName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique:true
  },
  deviceType: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description:{
      type:String,
      required:false   
  },
  deviceLocation:{
    default:Array,
    "default":[],
    required:false
  },

  Parameter:{
    type:String
  },

  Topic:{
    type:Array,
    "default":[]
  },

  AddedDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },

});

// User Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  location:{
      type:String,
      required:true,

  },
  createdDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },

  farm:[
      { farmName:{type:String,index:true}, 
        description:String,
        location:{type:Array,"default":[]},
        farmAddDate:{type:Date,default:Date.now},
        device:[{Device}]
     },

 ],


},
{strict:false}
);

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);


//Location Co-Ordiantes Schema
// const pointSchema = new Schema({
//   type: {
//     type: String,
//     default:"Point"
//   },
//   coordinates: {
//     type: [Number],
//     }
// });
```

Sample document:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5d3ac84a86688123789e13b2",
    "name": "Puja",
    "email": "puja@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$r17zOU1gTJvwoB.nBdRvi.qvDmsJhIlHbp//s8l0KEKgCEvbKoZAu",
    "location": "Delhi",
    "createdDate": "2019-07-26T09:30:50.243Z",
    "farm": [
      {
        "location": [
          "11.33,22.99"
        ],
        "_id": "5d3ff9d68e34cb265c030819",
        "farmName": "Xyz",
        "description": "Testing that info is  saved ",
        "farmAddDate": "2019-07-30T08:03:34.247Z",
        "device": [
          {
            "_id": "5d402def7cef9f20c8272fc4",
            "deviceName": " DeviceX01",
            "deviceType": " Test",
            "description": " This is a test",
            "deviceLocation": "11.22,33.12",
            "Parameter": " temp",
            "Topic": "v1/ DeviceX01/11.22,33.12/ temp"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "location": [],
        "_id": "5d42d171e7ceef2a90245470",
        "farmName": "Xilo",
        "description": "This is test from Postman Api Request",
        "farmAddDate": "2019-08-01T11:48:01.883Z",
        "device": [
          {
            "_id": "5d441878f1877637cc712d07",
            "deviceName": "Xki",
            "deviceType": "Muc",
            "description": "This is test for updation of specific data in a specfic farm .Test Pass",
            "deviceLocation": [
              "11",
              "180"
            ],
            "Parameter": "Hello Happy",
            "Topic": "v1/Xki/11,180/Hello Happy"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5d4418953968370e64c32e1f",
            "deviceName": "Xki",
            "deviceType": "Muc",
            "description": "This is test for updation of specific data in a specfic farm .Test Pass",
            "deviceLocation": [
              "11",
              "180"
            ],
            "Parameter": "Hello Happy",
            "Topic": "v1/Xki/11,180/Hello Happy"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5d4425548b3cf92af46e2c9a",
            "deviceName": "Xki",
            "deviceType": "Muc",
            "description": "This is test for updation of specific data in a specfic farm .Test Pass",
            "deviceLocation": [
              "11",
              "180"
            ],
            "Parameter": "Hello Happy 1",
            "Topic": "sagita/5d42d171e7ceef2a90245470/Xki/11,180/Hello Happy 1"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5d44256d8b3cf92af46e2c9b",
            "deviceName": " DeviceX01",
            "deviceType": " Test",
            "description": " This is a test",
            "deviceLocation": "11.22,33.12",
            "Parameter": " set",
            "Topic": "sagita/5d42d171e7ceef2a90245470/ DeviceX01/11.22,33.12/ set",
            "DeviceJson": [
              "{ \"$schema\": \"http: //json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#\", \"type\": \"object\", \"properties\": { \"_id\": { \"type\": \"ObjectId\" }, \"name\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"email\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"password\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"location\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"createdDate\": { \"type\": \"Date\" }, \"farm\": { \"type\": \"array\", \"items\": [ { \"type\": \"object\", \"properties\": { \"location\": { \"type\": \"array\", \"items\": [ { \"type\": \"string\" } ] }, \"_id\": { \"type\": \"ObjectId\" }, \"farmName\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"description\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"farmAddDate\": { \"type\": \"Date\" }, \"device\": { \"type\": \"array\", \"items\": [ { \"type\": \"object\", \"properties\": { \"_id\": { \"type\": \"ObjectId\" }, \"deviceName\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"deviceType\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"description\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"deviceLocation\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"Parameter\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"Topic\": { \"type\": \"string\" } }, \"required\": [ \"_id\", \"deviceName\", \"deviceType\", \"description\", \"deviceLocation\", \"Parameter\", \"Topic\" ] } ] } }, \"required\": [ \"location\", \"_id\", \"farmName\", \"description\", \"farmAddDate\", \"device\" ] }, { \"type\": \"object\", \"properties\": { \"location\": { \"type\": \"array\", \"items\": {} }, \"_id\": { \"type\": \"ObjectId\" }, \"farmName\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"description\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"farmAddDate\": { \"type\": \"Date\" }, \"device\": { \"type\": \"array\", \"items\": [ { \"type\": \"object\", \"properties\": { \"_id\": { \"type\": \"ObjectId\" }, \"deviceName\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"deviceType\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"description\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"deviceLocation\": { \"type\": \"array\", \"items\": [ { \"type\": \"string\" }, { \"type\": \"string\" } ] }, \"Parameter\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"Topic\": { \"type\": \"string\" } }, \"required\": [ \"_id\", \"deviceName\", \"deviceType\", \"description\", \"deviceLocation\", \"Parameter\", \"Topic\" ] }, { \"type\": \"object\", \"properties\": { \"_id\": { \"type\": \"ObejctId\" }, \"deviceName\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"deviceType\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"description\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"deviceLocation\": { \"type\": \"array\", \"items\": [ { \"type\": \"string\" }, { \"type\": \"string\" } ] }, \"Parameter\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"Topic\": { \"type\": \"string\" } }, \"required\": [ \"_id\", \"deviceName\", \"deviceType\", \"description\", \"deviceLocation\", \"Parameter\", \"Topic\" ] }, { \"type\": \"object\", \"properties\": { \"_id\": { \"type\": \"ObjectId\" }, \"deviceName\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"deviceType\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"description\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"deviceLocation\": { \"type\": \"array\", \"items\": [ { \"type\": \"string\" }, { \"type\": \"string\" } ] }, \"Parameter\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"Topic\": { \"type\": \"string\" } }, \"required\": [ \"_id\", \"deviceName\", \"deviceType\", \"description\", \"deviceLocation\", \"Parameter\", \"Topic\" ] }, { \"type\": \"object\", \"properties\": { \"_id\": { \"type\": \"ObjectId\" }, \"deviceName\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"deviceType\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"description\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"deviceLocation\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"Parameter\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"Topic\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"DeviceJson\": { \"type\": \"array\", \"items\": [ { \"type\": \"string\" } ] } }, \"required\": [ \"_id\", \"deviceName\", \"deviceType\", \"description\", \"deviceLocation\", \"Parameter\", \"Topic\", \"DeviceJson\" ] } ] } }, \"required\": [ \"location\", \"_id\", \"farmName\", \"description\", \"farmAddDate\", \"device\" ] }, { \"type\": \"object\", \"properties\": { \"location\": { \"type\": \"array\", \"items\": [ { \"type\": \"string\" } ] }, \"_id\": { \"type\": \"ObjectId\" }, \"farmName\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"description\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"farmAddDate\": { \"type\": \"Date\" }, \"device\": { \"type\": \"array\", \"items\": [ { \"type\": \"object\", \"properties\": { \"_id\": { \"type\": \"ObjectId\" }, \"deviceName\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"deviceType\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"description\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"deviceLocation\": { \"type\": \"array\", \"items\": [ { \"type\": \"string\" }, { \"type\": \"string\" } ] }, \"Parameter\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"Topic\": { \"type\": \"string\" } }, \"required\": [ \"_id\", \"deviceName\", \"deviceType\", \"description\", \"deviceLocation\", \"Parameter\", \"Topic\" ] } ] } }, \"required\": [ \"location\", \"_id\", \"farmName\", \"description\", \"farmAddDate\", \"device\" ] } ] }, \"__v\": { \"type\": \"integer\" }, \"farmModifyDate\": { \"type\": \"Timestamp\" }, \"lastModified\": { \"type\": \"Timestamp\" }, \"deviceModifyDate\": { \"type\": \"Timestamp\" }, \"deviceModified\": { \"type\": \"Timestamp\" } }, \"required\": [ \"_id\", \"name\", \"email\", \"password\", \"location\", \"createdDate\", \"farm\", \"__v\", \"farmModifyDate\", \"lastModified\", \"deviceModifyDate\", \"deviceModified\" ] }"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "location": [
          "11.22,65.33"
        ],
        "_id": "5d492a4a1294110f64196b2d",
        "farmName": "Durgapur",
        "description": "This is a test for frontend to backend",
        "farmAddDate": "2019-08-06T07:20:42.654Z",
        "device": [
          {
            "_id": "5d4bd62900b433276c2845af",
            "deviceName": "Farm @2 Device 001",
            "deviceType": "Intel Edision",
            "description": "This is a test for creation of Data Bucket of Topic",
            "deviceLocation": [
              "12.33",
              "56.33"
            ],
            "Parameter": "Temperature",
            "Topic": "sagita/model/5d492a4a1294110f64196b2d/Farm @2 Device 001/12.33,56.33/Temperature"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0,
    "lastModified": "2019-12-04T06:59:17.431Z",
    "farmModifyDate": "6764284414131175425",
    "deviceModifyDate": "6720517743902195713",
    "deviceModified": "6766475118035075073"
  }
]
```

Is there any other way so that I can get the parameter field by passing the farm._id and device._id?

Comment: can you add your `User` schema

Comment: Did you have a chance to check my answer?

Comment: yes , but I am having difficulty in executing the current aggregation pipeline and get the result as per request.get in this line```.exec((err,result)=>{
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(result)
    res.send(result)
  });```

Comment: @SuleymanSah its still returning empty array but your pipeline seems to working fine

Comment: @Pritam I will try to fix your query by updating the answer.

Comment: @SuleymanSah OK

Comment: @Pritam I updated the answer, can you check please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the order of second unwind and second match stage, and use the correct field names in the match fields.

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      "farm._id": req.params.farmID
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$farm"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$farm.device"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "farm.device._id": req.params.deviceID
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "parameter": "$farm.device.Parameter"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2zRoEqqONyM)

Also I would write my route like this:

```
router.get("/getParameter/:farmID/:deviceID", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await User.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          "farm._id": req.params.farmID
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$farm"
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$farm.device"
      },
      {
        $match: {
          "farm.device._id": req.params.deviceID
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          parameter: "$farm.device.Parameter"
        }
      }
    ]);

    if (result.length > 0) {
      res.send(result[0].parameter); //or you can return the object itself:   res.send(result[0])
    } else {
      res.status(400).send("No value found, check your request values");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
});
```

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't produce correct output, when I create an API .The status code is always 400 ```No value found, check your request values```

Comment: @Pritam please check your request params. As you see in the mongoplayground it works

Comment: yes Sir, I have checked it worked in mongoplayground,but I tried to know why it didn't ran on node.js server.Have you checked it,the api request?

Comment: @Pritam I believe this is a problem with your data, and how you send request params. I cannot say anything without seeing your data and how you send request.

Answer (score 0):

If the matching number of documents is limited then **$unwind** can be used. But if the matching documents are large in number then you should avoid **$unwind** operator as it is gonna increase the number of documents after breaking the original document.
In such a case you should try to filter the array in **$project** stage using the **$filter** operator.

Here is a sample query for your use case with avoiding $unwind operator:

```
    [ 
        { $match: { farm: { $elemMatch: { _id: "5d3ff9d68e34cb265c030819", "device._id": "5d402def7cef9f20c8272fc4" } } } }, 
        { 
                $project: { 
                        _id: 1, 
                        parameter: { 
                                $let: { 
                                        vars: { farm: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$farm", as: "f", cond: { $eq: [ "$$f._id", "5d3ff9d68e34cb265c030819" ] } } }, 0 ] } }, 
                                        in: { 
                                                $let: { 
                                                        vars: { device: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: { $ifNull: [ "$$farm.device", [] ] }, as: "d", cond: { $eq: [ "$$d.deviceName", " DeviceX01" ] } } }, 0 ] } }, 
                                                        in: "$$device.Parameter" 
                                                }
                                        } 
                                } 
                        } 
                } 
        } 
    ]
```